# Getting a wrong value from the macro function

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Recently I'm working on Macros and I got stuck in very simple problem. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define abs(A) (A<0)? -A:A;

using namespace std;

int dis(int x, int y)
{
   return abs(x-y);
}
int main()
{
    cout<<dis(2,4);
}
```

Basically `abs()` takes the absolute of the given value, then the distance is calculated. But in this case it gives the output -6 rather than the 2.

Comment: Accept the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: `abs` is a standard function (well, a set of overloaded functions, to be precise). Don't define it as a macro.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the way your macro will be evaluated, i.e. during the preprocessor stage of code compilation process, the `return abs(x-y)` would be changed to:

```
return abs(x-y)
(A<0)          -> -A
(2-4) < 0 = -2 -> -2-4 = -6
```

You should either change the definition of your macro (better solution), by wrapping macro variables in brackets, to:

```
#define abs(A) ((A)<0) ? -(A):(A);
```

or change your code to:

```
int dis(int x, int y)
{
   int res = x-y;
   return abs(res);
}
```

Please note that there is also a [`abs()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/abs) function in C Standard Library.